My magento 2 website is freezing and stuck due to debugger
(function anonymous(
) {
debugger
}) 

I am getting this in source tab and whole website is freezing because of it. I have not added this code anywhere. How to find out what is the exact issue.
Also when doing performance optimization- It is showing this - Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the URL you requested because the page stopped responding. Please suggest some method

Open this file
vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/web/js/resource/resize-observer/ResizeObserver.js

there is that function, might be someone added debugger in here if found remove it
return (function () {
            function anonymous() {
                this.__entries__ = [];
            }


Hello. I have checked that file but there is no such code
