razorpay for magento 2 facing issue on live website
from yesterday, suddently we are facing the issue due to razorpay payment gateway in magento2.
(function anonymous(
) {
debugger
})
checkout got messedup and had to disable it?
Any solution?

This post might help you in this context: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/375527/my-magento-2-website-is-freezing-and-stuck-due-to-debugger
